# Zend translate() function problem

Tags: php, zend-framework, internationalization, poedit

I'm using Zend Framework for a miltilingual site. Translating is done with Zend_Translate_Adapter_Gettext. I'm preparing the .mo files using poedit.

The problem is when I set up two msgids and one has a msgstr identical to the other msgid:

```
#: application/modules/foobar/views/scripts/index.phtml:1
msgid "foo"
msgstr "bar"
#: application/modules/foobar/views/scripts/index.phtml:2
msgid "bar"
msgstr "baz"
```

When I use this code:

```
<?php echo $this->translate('foo'); ?>
<?php echo $this->translate('bar'); ?>
```

the output is this:

```
bazbaz
```

I figure that if the msgstr coincides with a different msgid, it is used as if it was a msgid and thus is translated again. Please correct me if my reasoning is wrong.

Now, I'd like to know whether you've had a similar problem and how to circumvent it painlessly.

My current solution includes changing the msgids:

```
#: application/modules/foobar/views/scripts/index.phtml:1
msgid "KEY_FOO"
msgstr "bar"
#: application/modules/foobar/views/scripts/index.phtml:2
msgid "KEY_BAR"
msgstr "baz"
```

and then:

```
<?php echo $this->translate('KEY_FOO'); ?>
<?php echo $this->translate('KEY_BAZ'); ?>
```

This is not a satisfactory solution since I'm working on a community portal with ~10k files and I can't really check all of it for conflicts.

If it's of any use:

- Zend Framework version: 1.10.8
- poedit version: 1.4.6
- site runs on Apache 2.2.11 with PHP 5.3

[EDIT]

Thanks to Gordon, I can include another piece of data: a test involving PHP's `gettext`. I used the very same test .mo file, including "foo"->"bar" and "bar"->"baz" key-value pairs. The PHP code was this:

```
<?php
    putenv('LC_ALL=pl_PL');
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pl_PL');
    bindtextdomain("pl", ".");
    textdomain("pl");

    echo gettext("foo");
    echo gettext("bar");
?>
```

And the result:

```
barbaz
```

So it's definitely not `gettext`'s fault.

Comment: this might be related to http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-10418

Comment: can you do a test with PHP's [`gettext`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php) to rule out this is normal behavior.

Comment: @Gordon, thank you for your comment, I will edit my post in a minute to include the gettext test results.

Comment: @mingos do you have caching enabled? Does it also happen when you put the bar/baz pair before the foo/bar pair in the po file. Also, what happens when you translate('bar') before translate('foo')?

Comment: @Gordon and @mingos: The Zend_Translate Gettext Adapter is not implemented using PHP's gettext extension (source: Zend_Translate Adapter DOC: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.adapter.html)

Comment: @Tomas I asked to check with `gettext` to rule out that this is wanted behavior. I did not mean to insinuate that ZF uses the `gettext` extension. Sorry, if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @Gordon: Ok. I misunderstood it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the order

```
#: application/modules/foobar/views/scripts/index.phtml:2
msgid "bar"
msgstr "baz"   

 #: application/modules/foobar/views/scripts/index.phtml:1
msgid "foo"
msgstr "bar"
```